# This regex doesn't match the last two lines, but in theory it should

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text I'm trying to match

```
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [type] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [number_of_persons] [int] NOT NULL,
    [number_of_suitcases] [int] NOT NULL,
    [created_at] [datetime2](3) NOT NULL,
    [updated_at] [datetime2](3) NOT NULL,
    [description] [text] NULL,
    [number_of_children] [int] NULL,
    [number_of_small_suitcases] [int] NULL,
    [code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [sort_order] [int] NULL,
    [default_number_persons] [int] NULL,
    [margin_fixed] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [margin_percentage] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [car_type_id] [int] NULL,
    [recommended] [bit] NULL
)
```

And i'm using the following regex to match the comma's followed by a newline.

```
\,\s?(?![^\(]*\))
```

Which should work as follows:

[image: Explanation of regex]

But when I use it, it fails on my text above on the last 3 lines

[image: failing matches in regex]

I'm using it in javascript to split a the above string.

What causes the regex to fail in this example? it's worked flawlessly until this sample.

```
string.split(/\,\s?(?![^\(]*\))/);
```

**EDIT**

I forgot one other constraint the regex has to obey in case you wish to propose a fix.
This regex will also have to negate the text within constraint pushing it all in one big string, but match the first two. Which is what the current regex does.

Look at the output of testcase in the snippet below for what I mean.

```
[car_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [car_sales_combo_id] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_exitcontrol_carmanager_car_to_combo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [car_id] ASC,
    [car_sales_combo_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
)
```

```js
console.log("Testing regex fail");
console.log(document.getElementById('text').value.split(/\,\s?(?![^\(]*\))/));
console.log("Testing testcase it will also have to handle. The third array entry should be one big text blob");
console.log(document.getElementById('testcase').value.split(/\,\s?(?![^\(]*\))/));
```

```html
<textarea id="text">
  [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
 [type] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
 [number_of_persons] [int] NOT NULL,
 [number_of_suitcases] [int] NOT NULL,
 [created_at] [datetime2](3) NOT NULL,
 [updated_at] [datetime2](3) NOT NULL,
 [description] [text] NULL,
 [number_of_children] [int] NULL,
 [number_of_small_suitcases] [int] NULL,
 [code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [sort_order] [int] NULL,
 [default_number_persons] [int] NULL,
 [margin_fixed] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
 [margin_percentage] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
 [car_type_id] [int] NULL,
 [recommended] [bit] NULL
)
</textarea>
<textarea id="testcase">
[car_id] [int] NOT NULL,
 [car_sales_combo_id] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_exitcontrol_carmanager_car_to_combo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [car_id] ASC,
 [car_sales_combo_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
)
</textarea>
```

Comment: Your rules are not clear. You should list them with no superfluous wording.

Comment: @revo I added the sentence `Look at the output of testcase in the snippet below for what I mean.`

Comment: So you want us to decode things? Please specify rules. That's better.

Comment: As i understand you just want to capture the comma's followed by a newline. Please provide simpler and more clear instructions on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your regex does is matching a comma, optionally followed by a white space, and **isn't** followed by **a string without `(` ending with a `)`**.

For the last lines

```
[margin_percentage] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[car_type_id] [int] NULL,
[recommended] [bit] NULL
```

the negative look ahead fails, because all commas in those lines **ARE** indeed followed by **a string without `(` ending with a `)`**, since the types `int`and `bit`don't have lengths (no parentheses).

Answer (score 1):

This RegEx does capture the last "," of each line.

```
 (,\n)
```

Comment: Yea, and what about the test case. It matches all those comma's too and it shouldn't match those.

Comment: @Tschallacka You want last commas also match (*it fails on my text above on the last 3 lines*) so this answer is correct.

Comment: No it's not. It fails on the case with the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do can be achieved by simply dropping the negation of the `(` character

```
/\,\s(?![\(]*\))/g
```

instead of

```
/\,\s(?![^\(]*\))/g
```

Check here: https://regex101.com/r/VfQIJC/7

That way, you're checking for commas that aren't immediately followed by any number of `(` followed by a `)`.

Comment: I forgot to mention another constraint I have after I looked at the offered answers and wondered why. had to dig around. I amended my question. could you take a look again?

Comment: Will the constraints always be at the end?

Comment: Yes. I'm using sql server output, `script table as > create to > query editor window` I use another part of my workflow to filter out all the data that's superfluous and add indexes and constraint in my migration script. So I need that entire string within one string. Just like it is in my snippet output.